# JAVA GUI Drawing on a Coordinate System

Tags: java, swing, drawing, paintcomponent, shapes

[image: Coordinate System]

I have a class called "GridPanel" that paints the coordinate system on the screen.

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel
{
  protected paintComponent(Graphics g){
          // draws the Coordinate System with grid
  }
}
```

And another class called "Shapes" that paints custom shapes on the coordinate system.

```
public class Shape extends JComponent{
          protected paintComponent(Graphics g){
               // draws the shape on to the coordinate system
          }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to do the painting inside the shape class without having to paint the coordinate system again and again.

Comment: Make your `Shape` class some kind of awesome "drawable" class which your `GridPane` can paint, it'll be simpler

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can I control what to draw inside the GridPanel paintComponent() method?

Comment: Usually you'd have some reference to what you want to draw, maybe in a `List`, depending on your needs

Answer (score 2):

"How" will come down to "what".

Generally speaking, you'll find it easier to paint things onto the `GridPane` if you do it yourself, and not rely on things like layout managers.

For example.  This creates a simple `interface`, with a single method which is used to paint things onto the grid.

```
public interface GridShape {
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, JComponent parent);
}
```

This is then implemented by what ever wants to paint onto the grid

```
public class WaveShape implements GridShape {

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, JComponent parent) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        int xDiff = parent.getWidth() / 4;
        int height = parent.getHeight() - 1;

        int xPos = 0;

        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, 0, xPos, height, xPos + xDiff, height);
        xPos += xDiff;
        path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, height, xPos, 0, xPos + xDiff, 0);
        xPos += xDiff;
        path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, 0, xPos, height, xPos + xDiff, height);
        xPos += xDiff;
        path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, height, xPos, 0, xPos + xDiff, 0);
        g2d.draw(path);
    }

}
```

The `GridPane` then paints itself and then paints what ever "shape" it has (this example is pretty basic, but you could have a setter which changes the "shape" which is painted or, if required, have a `List` which allows you to paint multiple shapes simultaneously)

[image: WaveForm]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestGrid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGrid();
    }

    public TestGrid() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GridPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GridPane extends JPanel {

        private WaveShape waveShape;

        public GridPane() {
            waveShape = new WaveShape();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.dispose();

            // I don't trust you
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            waveShape.draw(g2d, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public interface GridShape {
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, JComponent parent);
    }

    public class WaveShape implements GridShape {

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d, JComponent parent) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

            int xDiff = parent.getWidth() / 4;
            int height = parent.getHeight() - 1;

            int xPos = 0;

            GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, 0, xPos, height, xPos + xDiff, height);
            xPos += xDiff;
            path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, height, xPos, 0, xPos + xDiff, 0);
            xPos += xDiff;
            path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, 0, xPos, height, xPos + xDiff, height);
            xPos += xDiff;
            path.curveTo(xPos + xDiff, height, xPos, 0, xPos + xDiff, 0);
            g2d.draw(path);
        }

    }

}
```